# Is it possible to use regular COM objects with C++/CX "hat" syntax?

Tags: com, windows-runtime, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, c++-cx

Since ref classes in C++/CX are essentially COM objects and can be used in C++ without "hat" syntax just like regular COM objects I thought that it would make sense for regular COM objects to be usable in C++/CX with hat syntax. Something like this:

```c++-cx
::DWriteFactory ^ h_factory(ref new ::DWriteFactory);
```

However this does not work. As far as I understand WinRT ref classes usable in C++/CX are actually declared as actual classes inheriting all the corresponding COM interfaces starting from `IUnknown` and those declarations are contained in .winmd metadata files. I was wandering whether it is possible to write some extra declarations to make regular COM objects to be usable with C++/CX syntax (without turning them into WinRT components), just like they have typings allowing regular Javascript code to be usable in Typescript for example.

Comment: Could go a long way.  But DWriteFactory() is just a plain C function that doesn't have anything to do with COM, the syntax can't work.  DirectWrite is as different from COM as WinRT is different from COM.  What they have in common is that they use an *interface-based* programming paradigm.  What is so, so different is the nasty little detail, the object factory.  Not little.  "Where does the code live" is a very big deal, DLL Hell and versioning are difficult problems.  `ref new` auto-generates code that calls RoGetActivationFactory().  Fail.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? C++/CX' `^` is very similar to WRL's `ComPtr` as far as automatic resource management goes. So just use the latter when dealing with COM objects in a Windows Runtime project.

Comment: Use of `^` seems to be more compact. I suppose that C++/CX also offers implicit interface queries so there will be no need to spam `ComPtr` variables and call `QueryInterface` (or `ComPtr::As`) manually for each interface implemented by target type (like it often happens when these interfaces don't form inheritance chain). Event if it is not really possible to construct ^ items using `ref new` syntax having some way to cast a pointer to constructed object to ^ item would be nice.

Comment: Essentially, you wish to sacrifice succinctness for more compact code. I'd advise against it. The handle to object operator (`^`) conveys to a reader, that there is auto-generated code involved. This is not the case with `ComPtr`. Making the latter look like the former eliminates a useful hint. Different things should look different. If you need a more compact way to express `ComPtr::As`, you can wrap it up in a function template of your liking.

Comment: Auto-generated code is basically what I *want* to get to replace the hand-written COM boilerplate. I don't see a way to make `ComPtr::As` more compact (it is rather compact as is) because it requires a new variable to be spawned; actually I would like it to be gone completely.

Comment: Arguably, you are looking for **compiler**-generated code, as a result of template instantiations. `ComPtr` already implements the entire resource management of COM, safely, including move semantics. No boilerplate on your end. If you need a more compact version of `ComPtr::As`, you can provide a function template that allows you to write `auto spItf2{ spItf1.as<IID_ITF2>() };`. As for implicit interface conversions in C++/CX, I believe those require an appropriate interface hierarchy as well.

Comment: Related: [Windows with C++ - COM Smart Pointers Revisited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn904668.aspx).

Comment: Constructs such as `auto spItf2{ spItf1.as<IID_ITF2>() };` are essentially a COM boilerplate that I want to get rid of. Implicit conversions in C++/CX are always performed by generating a call to `IUnknown::QueryInterface` as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2012/09/17/ccx-part-2-of-n-types-that-wear-hats/). And it looks like there are no interface hierarchies at all, each interface only inherits from `IInspectable`. For example `Windows::Application​Model::Package`: each of base interfaces is declared like `IPackage4 : public IInspectable {`.

Comment: Correct. And `Package` inherits from `IPackage1`, `IPackage2`, `IPackage3`, and so on. There's your hierarchy. Now if you pass a `Package`, you don't need any conversions to use **any** members of the aforementioned interfaces. The compiler knows how to call (COM) member functions in multiple inheritance setups, and emits appropriate `this`-pointer adjustments. I suppose you are trying to solve a problem which I haven't quite understood yet. Can you give an example of the type of code you wish to write?

Comment: As described at the page I've linked above compiler can not make any assumptions about the offsets of actual member functions corresponding to a particular interface and will call `QueryInterface` (and will also examine returned `HRESULT` and throw an exception if it fails). You can actually clearly see this when you look at [`Package` calls disassembly](https://pastebin.com/m8tPEyhb). And I'm dealing a lot with similar code, but I have to manually retrieve the interface that I need, check return codes, etc. It is quite a mess even with helpers such as `ComPtr` and `ThrowIfFailed`.

Comment: Even though you asked about the possibility to use C++/CX with regular COM objects, your comments suggest that you want the opposite: Use Windows Runtime types from C++ with the same ease of use as C++/CX. In that case you are looking for [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt).